# Stuck evaluating an indefinite integral using method of substitution.

Tags: calculus, integration

I am having trouble evaluating: 
$$\int x^5 \sqrt[3]{x^3+1} \, dx.$$

I put $u=x^3+1$ so that $du=3x^2 \, dx$ which would lead to $(1/3)du=x^2 \, dx$. I'm having trouble with this problem because I'm not sure how to deal with the $x^5$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your chosen substitution, $$u = x^3 + 1, \quad du = 3x^2 \, dx,$$ you also have $$x^3 = u - 1,$$ hence $$\int x^5 (x^3 + 1)^{1/3} \, dx = \frac{1}{3} \int x^3 \cdot 3x^2 (x^3 + 1)^{1/3} \, dx = \frac{1}{3} \int (u-1) u^{1/3} \, du.$$  Consequently, distribute the integrand to obtain $$\frac{1}{3} \int u^{4/3} - u^{1/3} \, du,$$ and the rest is trivial.

Comment: May I ask how did you get the middle equation?

Comment: If $u = x^3 + 1$, then $x^3 = u - 1$.  Then $x^5 = x^3 \cdot x^2 = \frac{1}{3} x^3 \cdot 3 x^2$.

Comment: Ah ok thanks so much